# Cant reassign a variable instance javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to take the results from the function addResults and assign them to the this.latitude and this.longitude respectively. I keep getting undefined. How do I reassign the instance variables?

```
// Fetch data from API
class Weather {
    constructor(latitude, longitude) {

        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
    // fetch weather from API
    async getWeather() {
        const response = await fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/fe1ff29d5df09ef94625244329e7b5e4/${this.latitude},${this.longitude}`);

        const responseData = await response.json();

        return responseData;
    }

    addResults(results) {
        this.latitude = results.results[0].geometry.lat;
        this.longitude = results.results[0].geometry.lng;
    }
}
```

Here is the code from app.js I am calling `addResults()` in the `convertGeoLocation` function.

```
// Init weather object
const weather = new Weather();
const ui = new UI();
const convertTypedLocation = new Convert('Redding', 'CA');

// Get weaterh on DOM load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getWeather);
// Get geolocation on load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', convertGeoLocation);

function getWeather() {
weather.getWeather()
    .then(results => {

        // ui.paint(results);
        console.log(results);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

// function getGeoLocation() {
//     getLocation.getGeo()
//     .then(geoResults => {
//         ui.getLocation(geoResults);
//         // console.log(geoResults);
//     })
//     .catch(err => console.log(err));
// }

function convertGeoLocation() {
    convertTypedLocation.convertLocation()
    .then(convertResults => {
       weather.addResults(convertResults);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: how and where to you call addResults? What is that data you pass into it?

Comment: @NickParsons addResults is called in my app.js file. I pass in the results of an API call from opencagedata that transforms a City and State location into GPS coordinates.

Comment: Show the code that calls it. Is it using `await`?

Comment: @Barmar added my app.js file underneath where `addResults()` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `addResults()` before calling `getWeather()`

```
// Init weather object
const weather = new Weather();
const ui = new UI();
const convertTypedLocation = new Convert('Redding', 'CA');
weather.addResults(convertTypedLocation.results[0].geometry.lat, convertTypedLocation.results[0].geometry.lng);

// Get weaterh on DOM load
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getWeather);
```

Comment: thanks @Barmar just a follow up how do I then pass the results I am getting for the latitude and longitude into my weather object.

Comment: Now I'm having trouble understanding what the code is trying to do. I assumed `convertGeoLocation` was using the results of `getWeather`, but now I see it's using `convertTypeLocation`.

Comment: what I am trying to accomplish is I am taking in an input from a user that is in the form of a city and state. I am taking that input converting it into latitude and longitude coordinates using the `convertTypedLocation`. I then want to pass the latitude and longitude up as arguments in my `weather` const at the top of the app.js file.